# How to extract the list of names using regexes in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I just started learning regexes and i have this simple text shown below:

```
text = """Mira is 15 years old, and her brother Danny is 12 years old. 
    Sarah and Jack, their parents, live in London."""
```

And i wanted to extract the list of names in this string. I'm using the following pattern but it won't give me the right result:

```
pattern = "[\w]* (?=is)"
result = re.findall(pattern, text)
```

And I'm getting only **2** names while it should be **4** names! can anyone help me knowing what am i doing wrong? to get the 4 names!
Thank you

Comment: You are checking for words that are followed by `is`. But `Sarah` and `Jack` are not followed by `is` so they are not matched... What can be a general rule for matching a name?

Comment: It's pretty easy to write a regex that will look for capitalized words, but I don't think it's possible to have a regex that will know that `Sarah` is a name but `London` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives you words, start with capital letters

```
>>> re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)', text)
['Mira', 'Danny', 'Sarah', 'Jack', 'London']
```

Comment: The question said it should give 4 names but here there are 5 names...

Comment: Of course, I understand that.

Comment: So if i want to use this answer the text should not include London because it starts with a capital letter.

Comment: @Ahmad hassan can you please tell me why you used A-Z and a-z in a separate square brackets?

Comment: The worst option, if you have a text file of your needed names, you can look up there if your text includes the names that are in that file.

Comment: [A-Z] is a set of letters from A to Z

Comment: [a-z] is a set of letters from a to z

Comment: i know but why it has to be in a separate square brackets? as i used to read it as something like [A-Za-z]

Comment: It means that give my the words that start by capital letter and have at least 1 small character after the capital letter